# Passing meta-characters to Python as arguments from command line

Tags: python, escaping, command-line-arguments, backslash

I'm making a Python program that will parse the fields in some input lines. I'd like to let the user enter the field separator as an option from the command line. I'm using `optparse` to do this. I'm running into the problem that entering something like `\t` will separate literally on `\t`, rather than on a tab, which is what I want. I'm pretty sure this is a Python thing and not the shell, since I've tried every combo of quotes, backslashes, and `t`'s that I can think of.

If I could get `optparse` to let the argument be plain input (is there such a thing?) rather than `raw_input`, I think that would work. But I have no clue how to do that.

I've also tried various substitutions and regex tricks to turn the string from the two character `"\t"` into the one character tab, but without success.

Example, where `input.txt` is:

`field 1[tab]field\t2`

(Note: `[tab]` is a tab character and `field\t2` is an 8 character string)

**parseme.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from optparse import OptionParser  
parser = OptionParser()  
parser.add_option("-d", "--delimiter", action="store", type="string",  
    dest="delimiter", default='\t')  
parser.add_option("-f", dest="filename")  
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()  
Infile = open(options.filename, 'r')  
Line = Infile.readline()  

Fields = Line.split(options.delimiter)  
print Fields[0]  
print options.delimiter  

Infile.close()
```

This gives me:

```
$ parseme.py -f input.txt  
field 1  
[tab]
```

Hey, great, the default setting worked properly. (Yes, I know I could just make \t the default and forget about it, but I'd like to know how to deal with this type of problem.)

```
$ parseme.py -f input.txt -d '\t'  
field 1[tab]field  
\t
```

This is not what I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> r'\t\n\v\r'.decode('string-escape')
'\t\n\x0b\r'
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way is to to `eval` it, like this:

```
eval(options.delimiter, {}. {})
```

The extra empty dicts are there to prevent accidental clobbering of your program.

Answer (score 0):

solving it from within your script:

```
options.delimiter = re.sub("\\\\t","\t",options.delimiter)
```

you can adapt the re about to match more escaped chars (\n, \r, etc)

another way to solve the problem outside python:

when you call your script from shell, do it like this:

```
parseme.py -f input.txt -d '^V<tab>'
```

^V means "press Ctrl+V"

then press the normal tab key

this will properly pass the tab character to your python script;

Answer (score 0):

The `callback` option is a good way to handle tricky cases:

```
parser.add_option("-d", "--delimiter", action="callback", type="string",
                  callback=my_callback, default='\t')
```

with the corresponding function (to be defined **before** the parser, then):

```
def my_callback(option, opt, value, parser):
    val = value
    if value == '\\t':
        val = '\t'
    elif value == '\\n':
        val = '\n'
    parser.values.delimiter = val
```

You can check this works via the command line: `python test.py -f test.txt -d \t` (no quote around the `\t`, they're useless).

It has the advantage of handling the option via the 'optparse' module, not via post-processing the parsing results.