# Can I pass "\t" to python from the command line?

Tags: python, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing meta-characters to Python as arguments from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753332/passing-meta-characters-to-python-as-arguments-from-command-line)

I want to pass a parameter from the command line to a python script to specify what my input file is delimited with. (e.g. `","` or `"\t"`). For flexibility's sake, I'd like to specify it directly on the command line, not code in options for this parameter into the script.

e.g.

```
pythonscript.py --in_delimiter "\t" --in_file input.txt
```

I seem to be having problems with the backslash being interpreted before python receives it. I tried to escape this by adding extra backslashes but couldn't get it to work.

**My Question:** Is it possible to pass something like "\t" from the command line or do I have to use codes which I interpret inside the script (e.g. `c = ","` or `t= "\t"`, etc).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: While it doesn't answer the broader question, one option for your particular situation would be to just make tab the default, and then only pass a delimiter if it differs.

Comment: What's wrong with the backslash being interpreted before Python receives it? Wouldn't that mean that the program receives a tab character?

Comment: Thanks Amber, I have set comma as the default currently (more common in my data), but you're right, it would solve my problem...

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: What is you shell? `python -c'import sys; print sys.argv' '\t'` passes `\t` as two characters in mine. You could use `.encode("string-escape")/.decode("string-escape")` to convert from/to Python bytestring literal form.

Comment: David - I would have thought it might be fine but in practise, split(in_delimiter) is failing to split the line of input by tab...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you doing it in Bash? If so, try:

```
pythonscript.py --in_delimiter $'\t' --in_file input.txt
```

Comment: +1, this is nicer than my answer because you can _see_ the tab

Comment: It's funny, I just learned about `$'...'`, after struggling with a similar issue for hours. Another hour was wasted when we tried this trick in a Linux script with `#!/bin/sh`: it won't work with sh! But with bash, yes.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to solve my problem!  Cool trick, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

On unix/linux, it's easy enough to pass the tab in. You need to quote it because it's whitespace

To type the literal tab, use `ctrl-v` `tab`

```
pythonscript.py --in_delimiter "   " --in_file input.txt
                                 ^
                                 | this is `ctrl-v` `tab`
```

Alternatively you could have a mapping for special cases

```
pythonscript.py --in_delimiter TAB --in_file input.txt
```

which you deal with in the code like this

```
in_delimiter = {"TAB": "\t", "COMMA": ","}.get(in_delimiter, in_delimiter)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I didn't know any of these :)